# Read files from S3 with DataFrameReader

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, databricks

Hi i have an issue reading files from S3 with DataFrameReader
i am able to read the exact same file when it is locally
but when it is stored on s3 i'm not able to read it, here's a snippet of my code

```
private SparkSession getSparkSession() {
    return  sparkSessionService.getTransformedCsvSparkSession();
}

public void processFile(StructType structType, String srcFile, String targetFile) {
    //"s3n://yourAccessKey:yourSecretKey@/path/
    String spark = new String("s3n://TTTTTTTT:YYYYYYY@/bucket-qa1/test/123456785_Ads_mockup_.csv");
    Dataset<Row> dfSpark = getSparkSession().read().format("csv").schema(structType).option("header", srcIncludeHeader).load(spark);
    dfSpark.show();
```

But i got this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid hostname in URI s3n://.....
```

i am using [DataBrics](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv):

How do i "tell" the DataFrameReader to read from AWS S3 ?

Comment: Is there a "/" in your aws access key or secret key? That will confuse spark. You can get the hadoop configuration from the spark context and set the keys there. The exact option names depend on the version of spark you are using.

Comment: no there isn't, how do i "split" between the Bucket  /  path / actual file name ?

Comment: You are splitting between bucket, path, and file name correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be a slash before the bucket name, its OK to have slash on the file path